# ImultiValueConverter error while converting from object to double

Tags: wpf, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

I'm using ImultiValueConverter and i want to convert two double values from two textboxes to double and multiply them and show the result in the third textbox
this is the code in the .cs file

```
public  class NE_charp_converter:IMultiValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object[] values, 
                           Type targetType,
                           object parameter,
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
         double RE_sharp = double.Parse ((string)values[0]) +
                           double.Parse((string)values[1]) ;
         return RE_sharp.ToString();
     }

     public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
                                 object parameter, 
                                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

and this is the xaml code here:

```
<TextBox x:Name="NE_charp_txt" Height="77" Margin="0,151,37,0" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
         Width="51.615" BorderBrush="Black">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NE_CONVERTER}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding ElementName="WBC_txt" Path="Text"/>
            <Binding ElementName="NE_percent_txt" Path="Text"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

BUT I got this message:
make sure your method arguments are in the right format

what is the right form to convert the object to double and return this value?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly like ***argument values in converter can't be parsed to double***. *(At time of load, passed values to converter will be empty string which can't be parsed to double. Hence error)*.

Use **`TryParse`** to see if value can be converted to double or not. If not return empty string else return sum of both double values.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    double firstValue = 0.0;
    double secondValue = 0.0;

    if (double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out firstValue) && 
        double.TryParse(values[1].ToString(), out secondValue))
    {
        double RE_sharp = firstValue + secondValue;
        return RE_sharp.ToString();
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```